# Universal Apps still support scheduled task agent?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to know whether Universal Apps still support scheduled task agent on WP8.1, if not, what is the substitute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 in Universal App project is based on Windows Runtime, which differes in quite many scenarios from good old Silverlight. Here you can find a decent summary regarding differences between Silverlight and WinRT (for a Windows Phone developer) - [MSDN about WP Silverlight compability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642084.aspx)

Article specifies that Silverlight 8.1 WP application can no longer define it's own ScheduledTaskAgents. So what can you do? I think this article is a pretty good place to start with - it covers the basics of handling scenarios when you want to use background tasks in your WinRT 8.1 WP application - [MSDN Background Tasks in WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx).

Comment: the second link is currently broken, I ended up with [Quickstart: Update a live tile from a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj991805.aspx)